# Need help re-grouping players in oTree's Python template language after a boolean input:

Tags: python, game-theory, otree

The idea is that players can select a true or false option and then true selecting players will be divided into random two person live game groups. If and odd number of players select the true option then I would like the random remainder to be moved to the false group. Also, I haven't taken a very good 'pythony' approach to this problem as im also unsure how to replicate this experiment with varying initial group sizes. 'participating' is the boolean field I define in the player section:

```
def after_all_players_arrive(group: Group):
    players_values = [group.get_players()]
    number_players = len(group.get_players())
    participating_list = [p for p in players_values if p.participating(True)]
    not_participating_list = [p for p in players_values if not p.participating(True)]
    group_1 = [],
    group_2 = [],
    group_3 = [],
    for player in players_values():
        player.participating_treatment = players_values.pop(participating_list)
        for i in number_players:
        ......
```

Im still working on my notation conventions and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do know set_group_matrix, right?